# Yammer API for commenting

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, yammer

I searched yammer docs. but was unable to find a way to get on How to comment through Yammer API ?
I assume to comment i need topic.
I posted a message with

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json.
```

Now I am trying to comment on it.
This is an ionic angular application

Help is appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Commenting is still done by the messages endpoint you mentioned. However, you'd need to provide `replied_to_id` as a parameter. `replied_to_id` is the value of the `thread_id` or `message_id` you want to reply to.  See https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post for details.